# How to create 'like' button in while loop so i can change his class name for every loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create like buttons in my comment box. Problem is that 
is in while loop so any button i click will update all buttons , and its
because class name of  where the output comes is same for all created
buttons.

```
 while{
             some  code ...

      <a ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" name="like" onclick="likeAdd()" id="like" role="button"></i></a>
                    <script>
                    function likeAdd(){
        $.post("ajax/add_like.php?id=<?php echo $id_koment; ?>",function(data){
            if ( data =='success')
            {
                likeGet()
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function likeGet(){
        $.post("ajax/get_like.php?id=<?php echo $id_koment; ?>",function(data){
            $(".likeCount").text(data);
```

> class of span for js

```
        });
    }
      </script>
                    <span class="likeCount"> 0 </span>
```

> class of span

```
    } end of while
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ID around as a parameter, rather than hard-coding it in your functions. e.g in pseudo-code

```
while (... as $id) {
    <i onclick="likeAdd(<?php echo $id ?>);">
}


function likeAdd(id) {
     $.ajax('/script.php?id=' + id, ....);
}
```